# JQuery .load JSP File

Tags: jquery, jsp, load, jstl

I am trying to load jsp file. JSP file is getting load but JSTL tags inside jsp are not getting rendered. Any thoughts? process.jsp has JSTL tags they are not getting rendered.

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
             $("button").click(function(){
               $("#holder").load("/process.jsp");
             });
           });
           </script>
           <button>Get Data</button>
        <div id="holder">   
        </div>
```

Comment: Does your `jsp` page load individually? I mean, without the ajax call?

Comment: Use tool like FireFug and check the actual HTML result and response code for the ajax request. It will give you the clue that your server really returned a page or some error

Comment: Firebug does returning any error, I am getting simple html output but no html output from jsp tags

Comment: Can you post the code for shobi-test.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, Tags scope was not define. Now it works